# MongoClient is abstract cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android, mongodb

I am developing an android application and I am trying to make a connection to a remote database hosted on [MongoDB Atlas](https://cloud.mongodb.com). Reading through their API they've provided a MongoClientURI, MongoClient and MongoDatabase type connection for Java. This looks like as follows:

[image]

The libraries I've imported look like:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI; 
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
```

I've also added the following dependencies in the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.9.1'
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:3.9.1'
}
```

And last but not least I added a INTERNET permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

I get an error on MongoClient object as shown on picture on the top saying -

*"MongoClient is abstract cannot be instantiated"*

I am not sure how to proceed and eventually resolve this issue. I am aware that abstract classes can't be instantiated, but that is what I have been provided with from the side of [MongoDB Atlas](https://cloud.mongodb.com) and their page  - ["Connect via driver"](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#driver-examples) showing how to connect using Java (Sync).

I feel I am missing something small, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 11):

The documentation you linked in your question seems to be outdated...

Look in the documentation of [MongoDB 3.9 driver for Java](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/driver/getting-started/quick-start/).

> You can instantiate a MongoClient object without any parameters to
>   connect to a MongoDB instance running on localhost on port `27017`:
>
> ```
> MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
> ```
>
> Or you can specify the [`ConnectionString`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.html):
>
> ```
> MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://hostOne:27017,hostTwo:27018");
> ```

Comment: It show you Python by default I was not aiming to point to Python documentation. Thank you for the answer, but do I have to connect to a localhost instance in order to access remote database ? Can't I just make the connection to the remote one directly ?

Comment: @Ne7WoRK 1. Yes, my fault. I've edited the answer. 2. You don't have to connect to `localhost`, you can connect a remote instance by using other connection string. It's just an example copy-pasted from the documentation.